# formatting in python 2.7.12

Tags: python, python-2.7, formatting

I am a beginner python programmer and I have learnt the format specifiers in the print statement.so, %3f will mean that the width of the floating point number should be 3.
But,in the following code,output is not like that

```
import math
print "%3f"%(math.pi)
```

this code should output 3.1 because we specified the width as 3.
but the output is 3.141593.
My questions:

1.Does specifying **only width** work for integers and not for floating point numbers?
2.is it must to specify both width and precision while formatting floating point numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying only width works also for floating point numbers. The thing is that the width includes decimal points too. For example, doing:

```
"%10f" % math.pi # '  3.141593'
```

As you can see, the string is 10 characters long. Another thing to take into account here is that by default, python will output 6 decimal points, so doing "%3f" is the same as "%3.6f".

```
>>> "%3f" % math.pi
'3.141593'
>>> "%3.6f" % math.pi
'3.141593'
>>>
```

That's why you are not getting your expected output `'3.1'`. To get that, and knowing the previous concepts you should specify:

```
"%3.1f" % math.pi
```

Or just:

```
"%.1f" % math.pi
```

Comment: your answer seems to the point,but I have a doubt.how could you guess that %3f is same as %3.6f?is it like there are always twice the number of decimal places as that of width?

Comment: @explorer No, it is always 6 by default. If you try `"%4f" % math.pi` it will still output 6 decimals, not 8.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just specify the part after the decimal point like this:

```
>>> print "%.1f"%(math.pi)  
3.1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also try the arguably better `.format` method. It offers much more clarity and functionality while formatting. This is will do what you need,

```
'{:.1f}'.format(math.pi)
```

You can also specify padding width,if needed, easily like,

```
'{:6.1f}'.format(math.pi)
```

You can read up more here https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> print "%3f" % x
99999.454540
>>> print "%.3f" % x
99999.455
```

Well the first one in `%30.1%f` specifies the length of the string/

```
>>> print "%30.1f" % x
                       99999.5
```

Look at this!

```
>>> print "%.1f" % x
99999.5
```

See the last one? It has it rounded off. If you don't want to round off then use `decimal` instead of float.

```
import math
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec=6
value = Decimal('999.559987').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
print str(value)
print '%.2f' % 999.559987
```

output:

```
999.55
999.56
```

Answer (score 0):

`%5.3f` here is two part. one is `integer '5' part` and another is `floating part '.3'`. integer part print the number of `space` before printing the number. And floating part specify how many number will print after floating point. And there are given so many example previous answer.